# What's a good way of converting timezone of a timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a string in this format:  09/20/2020 10:30 AM
That timestamp is in Eastern Timezone.
I need to obtain the UTC equivalent, but in the following ISO format: 2020-09-20T14:30:00.0000Z

I've tried a few things but there doesn't seem to be a clean/short way of converting it.

So far I've tried:

```
dtSept = "09/20/2020 10:00 PM"
dtSeptTZ = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(dtSept, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
```

`dtSeptTZ` at this point is a string object.
If I have to convert its TimeZone and format it, I have to execute the following which each take a datetime object but return a string.

```
dtSeptTZ.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Etc/UTC'))
dtSeptTZ.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M.%fZ")
```

Is there a clean/short way of getting the proper output without coverting it back and forth between string and datetime?

Many thanks.

Comment: short answer: no. you'll *have* to convert string to `datetime` object to convert to another time zone. Anything else would be highly error-prone in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to the immanent [deprecation of pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/), I'd suggest to use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The usage of `dateutil` also transforms nicely to Python 3.9's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil.tz import gettz

dtSept = "09/20/2020 10:00 PM"
# string to datetime object
dt = datetime.strptime(dtSept, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
# set tzinfo to appropriate time zone; (!) use "localize" instead with pytz timezone class
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=gettz('US/Eastern'))
# to UTC (could use any other tz here)
dt_utc = dt.astimezone(timezone.utc)

# to ISO format string:
print(dt_utc.isoformat())
>>> 2020-09-21T02:00:00+00:00
```